# Drop values satisfying condition plus arbitrary number of next values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So my final goal is to drop values in one column of a `pandas` `DataFrame` according to some condition on another column of the same `DataFrame`, **plus** several next values e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0,], 
                   'b': [0.1, -0.5, -0.3, None, 100., 0.2, 0.1, None, -0.3, -0.3, None, None, None]}, 
                   index=pd.date_range('2015/1/1', freq='D', periods=13))
df.loc[df['a'] > 0, 'b'] = None
print df
```

Result:

```
              a      b
2015-01-01  0.0    0.1
2015-01-02  0.5    NaN
2015-01-03  0.2    NaN
2015-01-04  0.0    NaN
2015-01-05  0.0  100.0
2015-01-06  0.0    0.2
2015-01-07  0.0    0.1
2015-01-08  0.2    NaN
2015-01-09  0.0   -0.3
2015-01-10  0.0   -0.3
2015-01-11  0.0    NaN
2015-01-12  0.1    NaN
2015-01-13  0.0    NaN
```

So this will drop the records where the condition is satisfied, but how do I drop the next 3 records after the condition was satisfied too? My desired output would look something like this:

```
              a      b
2015-01-01  0.0    0.1
2015-01-02  0.5    NaN
2015-01-03  0.2    NaN
2015-01-04  0.0    NaN
2015-01-05  0.0    NaN
2015-01-06  0.0    NaN
2015-01-07  0.0    0.1
2015-01-08  0.2    NaN
2015-01-09  0.0    NaN
2015-01-10  0.0    NaN
2015-01-11  0.0    NaN
2015-01-12  0.1    NaN
2015-01-13  0.0    NaN
```

Note that there could be sequential a > 0.

**[EDIT]**: I seem to have found a solution:

```
for pos, i in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(i['a']):
        pass
    elif i['a'] > 0:
        df['b'].ix[pos:pos+3] = None
    else:
        pass
```

Which is rather slow. So, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't your output only contain 0.1 and 100.0 at 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-05 according to your criteria?

Comment: @EdChum, so basically the idea is that if a is larger than 0 (any value basically), I need to discard b at that index and three values of b after that. If there are consecutive a > 0 occurrences, then three values of b after the last occurrence should be dropped, but also all the values of b when a > 0 should be dropped. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: But that is different to your loop code which is intentionally skipping `NaN` values which is not the same as what you've stated, that is a quite different

Comment: @EdChum, I added this check in case there are missing values in a, but for this particular example this check could be easily removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the boolean condition index to slice the df using `loc` and set the following values:

```
In [392]:
# take the first value of the index
idx = (df['a'] > 0).index[0]
idx

Out[392]:
Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D')

In [393]:
# we have to offset the range by 1 at begin and end points
df.loc[idx+1:idx+4,'b'] = None
df

Out[393]:
              a    b
2015-01-01  0.0  0.1
2015-01-02  0.5  NaN
2015-01-03  0.0  NaN
2015-01-04  0.0  NaN
2015-01-05  0.0  NaN
```

**EDIT**

This is an alternative method, extending the above answer which worked on your original edit data, the new method uses the same principal but we have to construct a timestamp from the index values so we can offset it:

```
In [39]:


idx = df[df.a > 0].index
for index in idx:   
    df.loc[pd.Timestamp(index, offset='D'):pd.Timestamp(index, offset='D') + 3,'b']=None  
df
Out[39]:
              a    b
2015-01-01  0.0  0.1
2015-01-02  0.5  NaN
2015-01-03  0.2  NaN
2015-01-04  0.0  NaN
2015-01-05  0.0  NaN
2015-01-06  0.0  NaN
2015-01-07  0.0  0.1
2015-01-08  0.2  NaN
2015-01-09  0.0  NaN
2015-01-10  0.0  NaN
2015-01-11  0.0  NaN
2015-01-12  0.1  NaN
2015-01-13  0.0  NaN
```

Timings however show that your method is twice as fast, unclear if my method will scale better as it depends on the size and distribution of your data.

Comment: Will this also work for a more complicated data like this: 'a' = [0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, None, 0, 0, 0.2] etc?

Comment: Yes, the key thing is that the index is monotonic and supports integer offsets, because your index is a timestamp with freqency of days then adding an integer to a timestamp index offsets the value as days so for this example it works, if the index is more complicated then you need to use a more complicated method

Comment: Okay, I figured that my data is actually not that simple. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Your solution is nearly an order of magnitude faster. I guess this is because `idx = df[df.a > 0].index` is a lot faster than iterating over every  single row. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would definitely be faster but I'm glad it is, you can accept my answer if it answered your question